# What is difference between Module Manager, Module Listeners and Module Loader?

Tags: zend-framework2

Could you please explain me, how Module manager, Listners and Loader related in zf2.

When a module is called, which one is loaded first, what is the flow.

how does following code will be used by these 3,

```
 public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this -> http://zendframework2.de/en/cheat-sheet.html This will answer your last question "What is the flow"

Answer (score 0):

ModuleManager attach some listeners to instance of eventmanager. We are intrested in AutoloadListener which is attached at highest priority - 9000. This means that it will be processed first. When loadModule event is triggered it creates AutoloaderFactory instance with autoloader configuration taken from Module's getAutoloaderConfig() method as parameter.